# Dynamic SQL throws error complaining scalar variable is not defined

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am copying my bulk data to SQL Server (table name: `TmpTable`) via C# code and then I want to update the table with following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Update_Locations
    (@lupdatedNoRow VARCHAR(10) OUT)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

    DECLARE @mttblfaximages3_sql NVARCHAR(500) ='UPDATE testAdmin.dbo.mttblFaxImages2 set fRemoteStorageLocation = temp.RemoteStorageLocation, fRemoteImageName = temp.RemoteImageName  from testAdmin.dbo.mttblFaxImages2 T INNER JOIN #TmpTable Temp ON (T.fFaxId=Temp.PrimaryId  AND T.fFaxPageId=Temp.SecondaryId); DROP TABLE #TmpTable;SELECT @lupdatedNoRow = cast(@@rowcount as VARCHAR)' 

    EXEC sp_executesql @mttblfaximages3_sql
            select @lupdatedNoRow

END
```

I see update works fine but c# throws exception after that

> Must declare the scalar variable "@lupdatedNoRow"

I want to return the number of rows updated.

How I should modify my stored procedure to return number of rows updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define & pass the variable `@lupdatedNoRow` into the `sp_executesql`

```
EXEC sp_executesql @mttblfaximages3_sql, 
                   N'@lupdatedNoRow varchar(10) OUTPUT', 
                   @lupdatedNoRow OUTPUT
select @lupdatedNoRow
```

Comment: Thanks Squirrel, once I update the SP as you said that error goes away but when I try to extract value for @lupdatedNoRow  in c# , it returns 0. Though I see in table update has happened.

Comment: move the `@@rowcount` to immediately after the update and before the drop table. `@@rowcount` returns the affected rows from last operation. In your case it is the `drop table`

Comment: Ohh Shoot I should have noticed that ! Thanks Squirrel ! Time to buy SQL classes online.